# Using Char does not compile without FlexibleContexts

Tags: haskell

```
sierpinski :: Int -> Array (Int,Int) Char
sierpinski l = runSTArray $ do
  arr <- newArray ((1,1),(63,32)) '_'
  let drawLine x y len = forM_ [-len..len] $ \s -> writeArray arr (x+s,y-len) '1' --this part does not compile without FlexibleContexts \\* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MArray a0 Char m (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
  let rek n x y h | n == 0 = forM_ [0..h-1] (drawLine x y)
                  | otherwise = do
                    rek (n-1) x y (div h 2)
                    rek (n-1) (x + div h 2) (y - div h 2) (div h 2)
                    rek (n-1) (x - div h 2) (y - div h 2) (div h 2)
  rek l 32 32 32
  return arr
```

However changing array type from Char to Int is okay

```
sierpinski :: Int -> Array (Int,Int) Int
sierpinski l = runSTArray $ do
  arr <- newArray ((1,1),(63,32)) 0
  let drawLine x y len = forM_ [-len..len] $ \s -> writeArray arr (x+s,y-len) 1 --now ok
  let rek n x y h | n == 0 = forM_ [0..h-1] (drawLine x y)
                  | otherwise = do
                    rek (n-1) x y (div h 2)
                    rek (n-1) (x + div h 2) (y - div h 2) (div h 2)
                    rek (n-1) (x - div h 2) (y - div h 2) (div h 2)
  rek l 32 32 32
  return arr
```

Can someone clarify why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is actually in the error message.

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: 
  MArray a0 Char m (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
```

When you use the literals `'_'` and `'1'`, Haskell infers that their type is `Char`, then it runs up against the most typical problem that you get with constraints that are `MultiParamTypeClasses` - constraints arguments aren't all type variables, yet that is what the Haskell report requires them to be. The signature Haskell *wants* to infer is something like

```
drawLine :: MArray a Char m => ...
```

This wasn't a problem before `MultiParamTypeClasses` since all classes before had only one argument. Then, if that argument was not a type variable, all you had to do was check that that instance was derivable and if it *was* a type variable, you'd keep it as a constraint. With `MultiParamTypeClasses` you often end up with in-between cases - some of the arguments are instantiated, some aren't. [`FlexibleContexts`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleContexts) lets you have this sort of mixture (and even some more). This is a safe extension (which I would love to see be part of Haskell 2020).

### But what about `Int`? Why doesn't it give me the same error?

It actually isn't directly about `Int`. When Haskell sees the literals `0` and `1`, since numeric literals are overloaded, it only decides on a general type: `Num a => a`. That means that the constraint Haskell infers is just

```
drawLine :: (Num n, MArray a n m) => ...
```

And this doesn't even need `FlexibleInstances` since all constraints have arguments that are type variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought based on **my understanding** - when you pass in a `Char` value, it is already a 'specialised' type. On the other hand, since you pass in numbers without explicitly typing, I believe that could be interpreted as passing a more general type i.e. `(Num a) => a`. That is why GHC complains for explicit `Char` literal, but not for the numbers.

Basing this off my understanding of the documentation [here](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleContexts):

> Haskell computes a type for each variable bound by let or where, and then generalizes this type. In Haskell 98, the allowed contexts are restricted, so contexts are reduced using instance declarations (and duplicate assertions and those implied by class contexts are removed) until either they are in the allowed form or no instance is applicable, in which case an error is reported.